# how to import highcharts offline-exporting in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

Tired out the following configurations but they dont seem to work.

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
/*import * as HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);*/
require('highcharts/modules/offline-exporting')(Highcharts);
```

get the following error:
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{}' has no compatible call signatures.

anyone knows how to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a solution

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import * as HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
```

this is good enough to work, a separate require command is not required.

Comment: it still not work for me, it still use online export. is there any setting? can you show the exportChart function parameters?

Comment: This should not working and you should use new option from the module using exporting() and offline()

Answer (score 4):

offline export highcharts:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import offline from 'highcharts/modules/offline-exporting';
exporting(Highcharts);
offline(Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
exporting(Highcharts);
```

The above code worked for me.

To export, use `chartName.exportChart()`.